# How to maximize or minimize $f(x)=ax^2+bx$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to self-study calculus from the Internet. I have learnt things mostly from [MIT OCW site](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/) and also from other sites. However, I am stuck on this simple problem:

> Find the maximum/minimum value of $f(x)=ax^2+bx$ (where a and b are constants)

First we can find the critical points by solving $f'(x)=0 \implies 2ax+b = 0 \implies x={-b\over2a}$.

But I don't think that is the solution, because $f(0)=a(0)^2+b(0)=0$.

So obviously, minimum or maximum should be $0$?

What have I done wrong?

(Sorry for asking such A basic question, I have just started learning calculus).

Comment: For $f(x) = x^2 -2x$ the minimum of $f(x)$ is achieved at $x = 1$ with $f(1) = -1$. Just because it's a quadratic function, it doesn't mean it's non-negative.

Comment: If $a\gt 0$, there will be an absolute minimum, reached where $2ax+b=0$. If $a\lt 0$, there will be an absolute maximum. Note that $ax^2+bx$ can take on negative values.

Comment: I have made an error in the previous comment. $f(0)=0$ does not prove that $x=0$ yields a min/max. It merely proves that the curve passes through the origin.

Comment: $x=0$ is a root, not a maximum/minimum. You have already found that to be $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$

Comment: @DarthGeek Thanks, I did not see the negative values. I got confused because I was looking at the graph of the positive values.

Comment: Since the answer seems to be accepted and the OP has fully understood the issues of his problem, I have nothing more to say but congratulations for learning by yourself! Keep on the good work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that,
since
$f'(x) = 2ax+b$,
$f'(0) = b$.
If $b \ne 0$,
then $f$ is either increasing
or decreasing at $0$,
depending on whether
$b > 0$ or $b < 0$.
Therefore
$f$ can not have a maximum or minimum at $0$
if $b \ne 0$.

If $b = 0$,
then $f$ does have
either a maximum 
(if $a < 0$)
 or minimum
(if $a > 0$)
at $0$.

Comment: Mine was downvoted also. Looks like somebody doesn't like how this question was answered.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum or maximum value (there will be one maximum or minimum) will be given by $$f\left(\frac{-b}{2a}\right) = a\left(\frac {-b}{2a}\right)^2 + b \left(\frac{-b}{2a}\right)= -\frac{b^2}{4a}$$

Indeed, the ordered pair, $$\left(\frac{-b}{2a}, -\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)$$ is the vertex of the parabola $ax^2 + bx$.

Whether the point is a maximum or minimum will depend on the sign of $a$.

- If $a<0$, then the parabola opens downward, meaning the vertex is
  where $f(x)$ attains its maximum, there being no minimum.
- If $a > 0$, then the parabola opens upward, meaning the vertex is
  where $f(x)$ attains its mimimum, there being no maximum.
- And of course, if $a = 0$, then we do not have a parabola, but rather
  a line, $y = bx$, with slope $b$ for which there is no maximum or minimum.  Certainly, if $b = 0,$ too,  we have then the horizontal line $y = 0$.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to explain the down-vote.

Answer (score 3):

If $a=0$, then $f(x)=bx$, which is trivial.

If $a\not =0$, then we have the following form:$$f(x)=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b}{4a^2}.$$

This is called *[parabola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola)* whose vertex is $(-b/(2a),-b/(4a^2))$.

Then, if $x\in\mathbb R$, we know the followings :

- When $a\gt 0$, $f(x)$ does not have the maximum and the minimum is $f(-b/(2a))=-b/(4a^2)$.
- When $a\lt 0$, the maximum is $f(-b/2a)=-b/(4a^2)$ and $f(x)$ does not have the minimum.

Comment: It is my answer and I left some details for the OP to do!!

Comment: I wrote my answer because I thought I could add more details. And *in my opinion*, adding more details is good for OP.

Comment: @amWhy: Well, I cannot agree with you. I've never repeated others' work on purpose.

Comment: @mathlove: The whole point is I leave some details for the OP to do since it is for their benefit to do some work if they really want to learn. Don't you agree?

Comment: A compromise would be to use spoiler tags. Unfortunately this feature is not known to everyone and folks then start to complain why part of the answer is not rendered. So I don't use that right now and hope I get how much detail is appropriate.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I understand what you mean. Again, in this case, *in my opinion*, adding more details is good for OP. But in general, to be honest, I sometimes feel difficulty how much I should write as an anwer.

Answer (score 2):

If you complete the square we get the parabola

> $$ y+\frac{b^2}{4a} = a\left( x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2 $$

with vertex located at the point $ \left( -\frac{b}{2a}, -\frac{b^2}{4a} \right) $. All you need now is just to know some properties of the parabola to determine your min and max. I leave it for you to carry on the task.

Comment: @amWhy: There is a difference of 2 minutes or less between our answers!! Do you really think I down voted your answer? I already left a comment for someone who posted his answer after 11 minutes of mine just to notify him.

Comment: I deleted my comment, Mhenni. (Note that I did not down-vote you, irregardless). I'm sorry if I was "off base." It just seems as though there are many down-votes flashing around this page!